# ¿Cómo pasar el Id de un item de una lista y pasarlo al controllador?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buenas gente el tema es así:

Tengo este método que trae la siguiente lista desde SQL:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.ZService.ToList());
}
```

esta lista es llamada desde otra vista mediante Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetAjax()
{
//toma la acción y el controllador donde se encuentra

    $.get('@Url.Action("Index","ZServices")', function (data) {
        $("#ajaxcontent").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

cada item de la lista tiene un botón "Agregar", lo que quiero es que cuando presione ese botón pueda obtener el Id de ese item en particular y poder pasarlo al controllador para hacer una nueva consulta:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Agregar(string id)
{
    var q = (from g in db.ZService 
             join ga in db.ZServiceOptions on   
             g.serviceid equals ga.serviceid where ga.value == id /*aca iría el id que tomaría dinámicamente*/ 
             select g).ToList();

        //q.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        return View(q);
}
```

Esto seria la vista html de la lista con su botón

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <ul>
    <li>
        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</span>
        <a type="submit" class="btnagre" name="Guardar"
           value="Agregar">agregar</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
}
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: `<a type="submit">`? Eso no existe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es enviar el id al `Action` *Agregar* de esta manera, reemplazando `<a ...> ... </a>` por lo siguiente:

### Utilizando Html Helper

```
@Html.ActionLink("Guardar", "Agregar", new { id = item.Id },
                                       new { @class = "btnagre", @name = "Guardar" })
```

El *html helper* `ActionLink()` te permite pasar en su tercer parámetro los `routeValues` en el mismo puedes especificar los parámetros de una ruta, en tu caso el parametro del `Action` *Agregar*. [Ver en MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd492936(v=vs.118).aspx)

En el cuarto parámetro defines los `htmlAttributes`, como por ejemplo la clase `CSS` que utilizaría y que nombre o id tendrá ese link.

### Sin utilizar Html Helper

```
<a href="~/TuController/Agregar/@item.Id" class="btnGrande" name="Guardar">Guardar</a>
```

**Atención:** *No se como se llama tu contorller, en todo caso reemplaza en el href `TuController` por como se llame.*

Comment: Funciona a la perfección,muchas gracias !

Comment: porque has quitado la respuesta aceptada? tuviste algún problema?

Comment: Perdon,se me escapo un click.

Comment: No te preocupes, pensé que ya no te servía la respuesta y necesitabas una mano.

Answer (score 0):

lo que deberías de realizar es incluir en la vista el id del item que lo estarías llamando por el onclick del botón.

```
       @foreach (var item in Model) { <ul>
<li>
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</span>
  <a type="submit" class="btnagre" name="Guardar" onclick="otroMetodo(@item.id)" value="Agregar">agregar</a>
</li> </ul>  }
```

Comment: Esto envía el `id` a una función JavaScript no al Action `Agregar`

Answer (score -1):

Primero, yo no usaría helpers como te recomiendan mas arriba, son cómodos y muy útiles, pero en caso de que algún día tengas que migrar tus vistas, estas estarás fuertemente acopladas al Framework/librería. Por lo cual te sería muy engorroso hacer una posible migración en otro ambiente (cambio de lenguaje, framework, libreria, etc)

Y para responder tu pregunta, lo que yo haría sería agregar un atributo  al elemento a (o en su defecto usar el href de toda la vida), para luego redirigir a la vista de tipo Get que responda a esta solicitud, o cancelar el Get y obtener ese href para ir a buscar una vista/datos por ajax y por ejemplo, procesar y mostrarlos en un popup.

Saludos.