# ¿Como enviar parámetros por medio de un ActionLink en MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito enviar a un controlador unos datos capturados en la vista, pero no encuentro como hacer esto. Estoy haciendo lo siguiente.

[image: Ejemplo]

Los datos que necesito enviar son 3, id usuario en sesión, el id del evento, y el id de la persona a registrar en el evento. Por el momento solo se como enviar el Id del usuario a registrar, pero los demás no se como hacerlo. Hago lo siguiente.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("AsistenciaEvento", "Create", new { usu = item.numIdUsuario})
```

le agradezco cualquier sugerencia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La extensión [`ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) como es un método sobrecargado puede originar algunos problemas a la hora de determinar el `linkText`,`actionName`, `routeValues` y `htmlAttributes`; en tu caso solo es necesario:

**Vista**

```
@Html.ActionLink("AsistenciaEvento", "Create", new { parametro1 = 1, parametro2 = 0, parametro3 = "1"})
```

**Controlador**

```
 public ActionResult Create(int parametro1, int parametro2, string parametro3)
 {
 }
```

---

Hay otras formar de definirlo, podrías revisar: [¿Cómo pasar el Id de un item de una lista y pasarlo al controllador?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2055/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-el-id-de-un-item-de-una-lista-y-pasarlo-al-controllador/2105#2105), debido a que necesitas enviar múltiples parámetros tu pregunta no sería dada como duplicado.

---

**Actualización:**

A lo detallado en el comentario, al invocar `ActionLink` de lado servidor genera un tag HTML `<a href=".."></a>` en el lado cliente.

Por ejemplo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Texto Link", "MiAccion", "MiControlador", new { id = 123, tipo = "0" }, null)
```

genera:

```
<a href="/MiControlador/MiAccion/123?tipo=0">Texto Link</a>
```

Por ende, si necesitas enviar valores del formulario por la url entonces *tienes que modificar la url del tag `a`*:

---

**Para solucionar tu problema**

En el controlado:

```
public ActionResult MiAccion(int id, string tipo)
{
}
```

En el formulario agregué un elemento de donde obtendrás su valor para concatenar a la url del tag `a`.

```
<select id="cmbTipo">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Usando JQuery para manipular los elementos.

```
(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        var $a = $(this);
        var url = $a.prop('href').split("?")[0];

        console.log(url);
        // http://localhost/MiControlador/MiAccion/1

        var parametro = {
            tipo: $('#cmbTipo').val()
        };

        console.log($.param(parametro));
        // tipo=1

        console.log(url + "?" + $.param(parametro));
        // http://localhost/MiControlador/MiAccion/1?tipo=1

        //e.preventDefault();

        $a.prop('href', url + "?" + $.param(parametro));
    });
})();
```

PD. *Al final, tu problema era realmente otro, no tenía nada que ver el ActionLink*

Comment: Hola @Davlio, entiendo parte de tu respuesta, pero lo que no se es como capturo los demás parámetros (el valor de lo elegido en el dropdownlist, por ejemplo), no los puedo enviar "quemados" ya que no lo son, este ActionLink lo genero de forma recursiva

Comment: @jeissoni22 en ese caso, no es necesario que uses la extensión `ActionLink`. Lo que me indicas es la interacción a nivel de cliente. Voy a modificar mi respuesta.

Comment: @jeissoni22 Como te decía en el comentario anterior, ya terminé actualizar mi respuesta.